# OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files on python import

Tags: linux, python-3.x

i have a testing environment that calls python from c code with:

```
system("flows_parser.py ....");
```

after a long while running i get this error every time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/homes/fw/antvai01/work/cc312r2/cc_validation/hta/flows_parser/flows_parser.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "/homes/fw/antvai01/work/cc312r2/cc_validation/hta/flows_parser/../../shared/proto_steps/common/generated_py/proto_steps_common_steps_defines_pb2.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 661, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 766, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 818, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/protobuf/reflection.py'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 661, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 766, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 818, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/homes/fw/antvai01/work/cc312r2/cc_validation/hta/flows_parser/flows_parser.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "/homes/fw/antvai01/work/cc312r2/cc_validation/hta/flows_parser/../../shared/proto_steps/common/generated_py/proto_steps_common_steps_defines_pb2.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 661, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 766, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 818, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/google/protobuf/reflection.py'
```

flows_parser.py line 32 in an import of proto_steps_common_steps_defines_pb2
proto_steps_common_steps_defines_pb2.py line 9 is also an import of reflection.

i'm on Ubuntu 16.4 
output of: sysctl -A | grep shm

```
kernel.shm_next_id = -1
kernel.shm_rmid_forced = 0
kernel.shmall = 18446744073692774399
kernel.shmmax = 18446744073692774399
kernel.shmmni = 4096
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.all.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.default.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.enp0s3.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.enp0s8.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.lo.stable_secret"
vm.hugetlb_shm_group = 0
```

so shmmax should not be an issue.
can anybody help?

Comment: What is the output of `ulimit -n`?

Comment: $ ulimit -n :
1024

Comment: Try to increase this soft limit to the value reported by `ulimit -Hf` running `ulimit -f $(ulimit -Hf)`.  Your program may have a file descriptor leak.

Comment: i cant think of any files that remain open after the python exits and i get back to the c program

Comment: any way to see how many file descriptors my process has open?

Comment: ulimit -Hf is unlimited and after ulimit -f $(ulimit -Hf) its still 1024

Comment: Sorry, it's `ulimit -f $(ulimit -Hn)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks Ricardo Branco!
it was a descriptor leek from the c code and had nothing to do with python.
i created pipes and didnt close them when i was done.
i found the descriptor leek and plugged it, now its working fine.